# LIBLINEAR with Weka

Tags: weka, liblinear

I'm using Weka 3.6.11 and I want to use its LibLinear wrapper.

I get the message that "Liblinear classes not in CLASSPATH"

I am on Windows. I create the CLASSPATH to the system variables, and wrote the path to the liblinear.jar file which happens to be

C:\Program Files (x86)\Weka-3-6\LibLINEAR.jar

So now, I'm not sure what the problem is. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't exactly resolved my issue but when I used Weka 3.7 instead of 3.6 and used the Weka Package manager to install LibLinear and LIBSVM, they worked just fine.